# delete multiple rows of a table where this data came from another select in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this code:

```
SELECT movieid FROM genres WHERE genre ='Action'
```

This shows me all `movieid` values from the `genre` table that match the condition.

How can I collect this data from the select to delete the same `movieid` from another table?

(*don't tell me to use DELETE ON CASCADE because I've tried so hard and couldn't apply it*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete from anotherTable 
        where movieid in 
             (SELECT movieid FROM genres WHERE genre ='Action')
```

See if this helps

Comment: OMG. That is perfect! Thank you a LOT. Really.

You just saved me hahahaha

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

You will see the example:

```
DELETE FROM films
  WHERE producer_id IN (SELECT id FROM producers WHERE name = 'foo');
```

Which matches what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, Turophile. You and User2012384 helped me on my way. I'm really grateful!